# View EC2 Instance Server Files in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to browse server files (.php, etc.) inside the AWS Console (in the browser) and not via a SSH or FTP client? For example; view files just like in CPanel on a regular web host.

I am working on a EC2 instance of a Debian OS that was created by someone else and who didn't save the private key (.pem). We just need to see what files are in there and structure not update. So the easiest way is just to view the files in the AWS Console.

Note the former person didn't create any Buckets either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is no. you cannot view the files in the AWS console.
depending on the instance type, if it's EBS backed you may be able to snapshot the volume and start the machine with a new SSH key pair you do have access to.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think you are saying to create an image (AMI) and then relaunch it and generate a new key pair? Would a second EC2 instance incur any/more costs? The server would be micro t2 and a free OS/Server.

Comment: yes. in general, a new instance will cost you money but you will get to look into what's inside, if that's the goal.

Comment: if costs are a issue you can kill the previous instance after you snapshot, before you bring up the new instance, but I would not recommend this until you are sure the new instance starts correctly and you make sure you can access it